# How do I write a regex that ignores strings starting with a particular prefix, and captures everything else into a single group?

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

**Background:**

I'm trying to come up with a regex for a rewrite rule that will take anything that does not start with a particular prefix, and add that prefix to it.  But urls that already have the prefix should be rejected by the regular expression (because they already have the url).

**Example:**

If the prefix is `s1` a string like `home` will capture the `home` part. But a string like `s1/home`, will not capture anything.

This way I can add the capture group onto the prefix, so that 'home' will become 's1/home'.

I've tried `(^s1/)`, but I'm missing something here, because that rejected 'home' for some reason.

Comment: Are you talking about mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!prefix)(.+)
```

replace with

```
prefix$1
```

Explanation:

```
^         # start-of-string
(?!       # begin negative look-ahead
  prefix  # your prefix (take care to properly regex-escape it)
)         # end negative look-ahead
(.+)      # capture the complete string to group $1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your awesome answer, it works well, and I will no doubt select your answer.  But I was wondering if you could tell me how to modify the regex so that it could also select an empty string?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```
^(?!s1).*(home)
```

This will match `home` in any string that does not start with `s1`.